# INSERT INTO..SELECT and store result

Tags: sql, sql-insert

I'm wondering if it is possible to use an **INSERT INTO...SELECT** to insert **and** to store and bind the result from the select query.

**Working INSERT INTO..SELECT (not storing the result):**

```
$query = "INSERT INTO reportmessage (header, sentdate, senttime, ip)
          VALUES ((SELECT header
                   FROM conversation 
                   WHERE id = ?), ?, ?, ?)";

          $stmt = $dbconn->prepare($query);
          $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $convid, $date, $time, $ip);
          if ($stmt->execute() == false) {
            $flag = false;
          }
          $stmt->close();
```

**What I want to accomplish if possible (not working, throws an *Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean error*):**

```
$query = "INSERT INTO reportmessage (header, sentdate, senttime, ip)
          VALUES ((SELECT c.header, c.useroneFK, c.usertwoFK
                   FROM conversation c
                   WHERE c.id = ?), ?, ?, ?)";

          $stmt = $dbconn->prepare($query);
          $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $convid, $date, $time, $ip);
          if ($stmt->execute() == false) {
            $flag = false;
          }
          $stmt->bind_result($header, $useroneFK, $usertwoFK);
          $stmt->fetch();
          $stmt->close();
```

Comment: your second select returns three values and you add another three, but you just want to insert four - this doesn't add up

Comment: The only select is getting the header which is to be inserted, this works in the first code example. In the second example (what I want to accomplish) it is getting the header to be inserted and then the user id's to be bound and fetched as variables. The three to be stored and the four to be used for insert and fetching.

Comment: problem is, your inner SELECT returns three values which end up inside the outer INSERT, where you don't want to have them - Idon't see how you can do this in one operation. Probably better to build a temp table with the results of the SELECT

Comment: When you want to use a query as the source for an insert, don't use `values`. A plain: `insert into (...) select ... ` should do

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?  "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So want to use the same `SELECT` for inserting data and for getting the results in PHP, in order to avoid querying the same data twice. I'm afraid that you can't do that because:

- You are performing an `INSERT` operation and `INSERT` operations usually doesn't return a result set, only the number of rows affected. That you are using a `SELECT` for getting the data doesn't change it, is just another variant of an `INSERT` operation.
- Also you want to return more values that the ones needed for the `INSERT`. Even if there was a way in your RDBMS for returning the data being inserted you are just adding arbitrary values that aren't needed for the insert operation.

You have several options for getting the data:

1. If the query you put in the sample is the real query, just perform another `SELECT`, if you have an index on `id` the extra work for the second query would be almost negligible.
2. If the real query is a very complex one from several tables with a lot of rows that take a noticeable time to execute, you can:

   - Store the results in a temporal table as suggested in the comments and use it for getting the data for the `INSERT` and for the `SELECT` that would return the results.
   - Or if the insert would be always for one row just perform the `SELECT` and then construct a `INSERT .. VALUES(...)` from PHP using the data from the `SELECT` (you could do this for more that one row but it would be more cumbersome).

Comment: "*and INSERT operations doesn't return a result set*" - not true. There are some DBMS where you _can_ make the INSERT return the rows it just inserted as a result set (but that requires an additional option/keyword for the INSERT statement)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I suspected it, that's is why added the second point, but I'll edit the question to make that statement less affirmative.